# Hibernate One to One Mapping

Tags: hibernate-mapping

I have two class

```
Class Item
{
   private Auction CorrespondingAuction;
}

Class Auction
{
    private Item CurrentItem;
}
```

Can someone tell how to set this one to one mapping in XML, it must be bidirectional

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Auction XML FILE:

```
 <many-to-one name="CurrentItem" class="com.BiddingSystem.Models.Item" fetch="join"
            not-null="true" cascade="all" unique="true" lazy="false">
            <column name="CURRENTITEM" />
 </many-to-one>
```

In Item XML File:

```
<one-to-one name="auction" class="com.BiddingSystem.Models.Auction" property-ref="CurrentItem"/>
```

property-ref refers to the name of the variable corresponding to class item in the auction class

Answer (score 6):

Bookmark [this cheat sheet](http://ndpsoftware.com/HibernateMappingCheatSheet.html).This shows simple examples of all the mappings supported by Hibernate.

Comment: To others: it is a nice reference, but it is XML based.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have PK in common:

```
Class Item {
    @Id
    Long id;
    @OneToOne
    private Auction CorrespondingAuction;
}

Class Auction {
    @Id
    Long id;
    private Item CurrentItem;
}
```

The ID for Auction is taken from the ID already generated for Item

Comment: The XML mapping names are the same as the annotations